# Refresh div after form submitted?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, refresh

I have a form with results (amount of products left in stock) pulled from my data from a database. The user is able to add and subtract to the stock using a form with 2 buttons (one to add and one to subtract). The results are in the same table on the same page.

What I'd like to see is the results updated as soon as it is submitted.

Because of this, I use the following code:

```
 $(function() {       //run when the document's ready, elements are loaded
  $("form").submit(function() {
    $("#resultaten").load(location.href + " #resultaten > *");
  });
});
```

The whole table is in the id 'resultaten'. 
When I have an image and use the following code, it does work (but only after the user clicks on the image, not on submit)

```
$(function() {       //run when the document's ready, elements are loaded
  $("#image").click(function() {
    $("#resultaten").load(location.href + " #resultaten > *");
  });
});
```

Is anybody out there with any idea how to make this work?

My complete HTML:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xx","xx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("aantal", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM voorraad");

echo "<div id='resultaten'><table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Aantal</th>
<th>Aantal erbij/eraf</th>
<th>Erbij</th>
<th>Eraf</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<form name='form' method='post'><tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['product'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='aantal-" . $row['stock'] . "'>" . $row['stock'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' name='aantal'></td>";
  echo "<td><input class='vernieuwknop' type='submit' name='add' value='+'></td>";
  echo "<td><input class='vernieuwknop' type='submit' name='subtract' value='-'></td>";
  echo "<td><input style='display: none;' type='text' name='idtje' value='" . $row['id'] . "'></td>";
  echo "</tr></form>";
  }
echo "</table></div>";

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $add=$_POST['aantal'];
    $idtje=$_POST['idtje'];
    $query="update voorraad set stock=stock+$add where id=$idtje";
    mysql_query($query) or die("Cannot update");
}
if(isset($_POST['subtract'])){
    $subtract=$_POST['aantal'];
    $idtje=$_POST['idtje'];
    $query="update voorraad set stock=stock-$subtract where id=$idtje";
    mysql_query($query) or die("Cannot update");
}


mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: It would help if you made your exact question more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you said, when you click the image, it reloads the `div` properly but not on submit event of the form. The problem - your page must be getting refreshed after submitting the form. If that is the case, then you have to disable the default form submission by putting `return false` at the end of the function.

```
 $("#image").click(function() {
    $("#resultaten").load(location.href + " #resultaten > *");
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: I may not have been clear enough, but what I'm trying is to refresh it without using the image (because the image works the way I posted it). I want it to refresh when clicking on the button, without even having an image.

Thanks for taking a look though!

Comment: `What I'd like to see is the results updated as soon as it is submitted.` - what do you mean by this? Does not it work as intended?

Comment: When I currently submit the page, I do not see the changes immediately. I only see when I refresh the page.

Comment: ok. Do you see the XHR request in the console when you submit the form? Are you sure it runs the code written inside `.submit()` event.

Comment: It does not show any XHR request (but it does make the changes). I'm not sure what you mean by your second question, but I use `$("form").submit(function() {`, so it should take every form, right?

Comment: As you said it does update the DB or something, you should check what you get back as a response to your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider having that PHP code be in a separate php file so it can be called from whatever page you're on and be displayed in a DIV.

Instead of using a load, you can use innerHTML after modifications have taken place

So, after you've made changes to stock, re-run a query to display the updated information.

**AJAX**

```
var stockDisplay = document.getElementById('stockDiv');
stockDisplay.innerHTML = queryResult;
```

Where `queryResult` is the formatted HTML to insert back into your DIV.

This won't be appropriate however if what you're trying to display is a ton of HTML, but if it's something simple like what you've posted, this will work nicely and it will update the DIV without reloading the page.

Comment: I can't seem to work this out. Mind you, I'm still a beginner with PHP and all, so I tried the following: `var stockDisplay = document.getElementById('resultaten');
stockDisplay.innerHTML = queryResult;` (changed stockDiv to resultaten) since this was the name of the div.

However, I get the error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR in C:\xampp\htdocs\2golocal\aantal\aantal.php on line 79'.

It's probably something really easy but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so I just realised I need to place this in the jQuery. doh. My jQuery looks like this now: `$(function() {       //run when the document's ready, elements are loaded
 $(".vernieuwknop").click(function() {
    $("#resultaten").load(location.href + " #resultaten > *");
 
 });

 var stockDisplay = document.getElementById('resultaten');
stockDisplay.innerHTML = queryResult;

 
});`

It does submit the form now, but it still does not show the updated data.

Comment: See my other answer, might be a better start.  Sorry it's not really complete or tested but should set you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Like *codef0rmer* said you are using a submit function which refreshes the page.

submit(function()) - refreshes page, unless you put return false;

click(function()) - doesn't refresh page

You can use a click function for the submit instead of submit and handle the outputs manually.

Comment: This does not work unfortunately, when I use the click(function()) it does not submit the form.

Comment: That is the whole idea, that you do not need to submit the form to get the values. You can use ajax to complete the circle and send the server all inputs you want. And because its not submitted, its not refreshed, and it happens instantly. Check XToro's answer for ajax

Comment: So what you're saying is, ignore the post method from the HTML tag and use Ajax to submit the form? I have no experience with Ajax so this'll be a little though for me, but this might be a better solution for me at the end. Thanks.

Comment: Not at all, you can choose which method you can use (GET/POST) but instead of using default method of submitting with refresh page, use AJAX to submit the data to the server. Google AJAX TUTORIALS to get started on ajax

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this.

Sorry I haven't really finished it or tested it but it should set you on the right track

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

Some content here

<div id='resultaten'>
<?PHP
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xx","xx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("aantal", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM voorraad");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Aantal</th>
<th>Aantal erbij/eraf</th>
<th>Erbij</th>
<th>Eraf</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<form name='form' method='post'><tr>
    <td>".$row['product']."</td>
    <td class='aantal-".$row['stock']."'>".$row['stock']."</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='aantal'></td>
    <td><input class='vernieuwknop' type='button' name='add' value='+'  onclick=\"addFunc('".$row['id']."')\"></td>
    <td><input class='vernieuwknop' type='button' name='subtract' value='-'  onclick=\"subFunc('".$row['id']".')\"></td>
    </tr></form>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
</div>

More Content if you want....

<script type="text/javascript">

function addFunc(rowID) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "update.php?add=+?idtje="+ rowID ,
    success: function(html) {
    if(html){       
        $("#resultaten").innerHTML=html;
        }
    }
    });
}


function subFunc(rowID) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "update.php?subtract=-?idtje="+ rowID ,
    success: function(html) {
    if(html){       
        $("#resultaten").innerHTML=html;
        }
    }
    });
}

</script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**UPDATE.PHP**

```
<?PHP
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xx","xx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("aantal", $con);

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $add=$_POST['aantal'];
    $idtje=$_POST['idtje'];
    $query="update voorraad set stock=stock+$add where id=$idtje";
    mysql_query($query) or die("Cannot update");
}
if(isset($_POST['subtract'])){
    $subtract=$_POST['aantal'];
    $idtje=$_POST['idtje'];
    $query="update voorraad set stock=stock-$subtract where id=$idtje";
    mysql_query($query) or die("Cannot update");
}    

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM voorraad");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Aantal</th>
<th>Aantal erbij/eraf</th>
<th>Erbij</th>
<th>Eraf</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<form name='form' method='post'><tr>
    <td>".$row['product']."</td>
    <td class='aantal-".$row['stock']."'>" .$row['stock']."</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='aantal'></td>
    <td><input class='vernieuwknop' type='button' name='add' value='+'  onclick=\"addFunc('".$row['id']."')\"></td>
    <td><input class='vernieuwknop' type='button' name='subtract' value='-'  onclick=\"subFunc('".$row['id']".')\"></td>
    </tr></form>";
  }
echo "</table>";



mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: This might seem like a lot to look at at first, but all the PHP code in the `resultaten` div of index.php is the same as what's in update.php, except that update.php has the 2 `IF` statements to add or subtract from your table.  This allows the `resultaten` div to be populated the first time the page is loaded.  And notice the + and - buttons now call a function onclick that will call the update.php and send it values to do what you want (The row ID).  Then the div is updated with the newest `SELECT` results that come from update.php.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the code! I just tried this but got an error,
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\2golocal\aantal\index.php on line 33`

I noticed this was cause of the addFunc and subFunc, so I changed the codes to
`{?>
<td><input class='vernieuwknop' type='button' name='add' value='+'  onclick="addFunc('.$row[\'id\'].')"></td>
<td><input class='vernieuwknop' type='button' name='subtract' value='-' onclick="subFunc('.$row[\'id\'].')"></td>
<?php }
` in index.php and update.php, however after that, the page shows but does not work.

Comment: Ah, I messed up some of the quoting and escaped something I shouldn't have.  Try it again, I edited the code I posted.  I changed the `echo` that's in the while loop (For both index and update).  You don't need to make several individual echo lines, just one will work even if it's multiple lines like how I changed it to.

Comment: Thanks! Although something is still wrong in line 35 (Can't seem to figure this out again!) `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\2golocal\aantal\index.php on line 35`